# How to implement a function that differentiates between the length of a string and the characters within that string

Tags: python

The question given is : How to implement a function so that it returns True if the input strings are the same length and differ at exactly one character position, and returns False otherwise.
I'm looking to return true or false depending on if the input strings are the same length and differ at exactly one character position. What I have now tells me if they're the same length but fails when given the same set of letters in a different order.

```html
def sameordiffernt(string1,string2):
     str1 = string1.lower()
     str2 = string2.lower()
     count = 0
     if len(str1) == len(str2):
         print ('true1')
     else:
         print('false1')
         count = count +1
     while str1 == str2:
        print('true2')
     else:
         print('false2')
         count = count + 1
     if count == 2:
         print('false3')
     else:
         print('true')
     return
```

Comment: Can you give an example of this?  "strings are the same length and differ at exactly one character position"

Comment: "car", "arc" same set of letters but different placement.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to see if this works:

```
def sameOrDifferent(param1, param2):
    str1 = param1.lower()
    str2 = param2.lower()
    count = 0

    numDiff = 0
    if len(str1) == len(str2):
        for index in range(len(str1)):
            if str1[index] != str2[index]:
                numDiff = numDiff + 1
        return numDiff == 1
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use in-built `zip()` function for a pythonic solution:

```
def sameOrDifferent(s1, s2):
    for (c1, c2) in zip(s1, s2):
        if c1 != c2:
            print('False')
            return False;
    
    print('True')
    return True

sameOrDifferent('car', 'car') # True
sameOrDifferent('car', 'caw') # False
```